# Static LAG and VLAN Trunking Differences?

Tags: networking, switch, vlan, lag

What is the difference between Static LAG and VLAN Trunking and which would be better to use going from Switch to Switch with CAT5 in a VLAN environment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two technologies do not overlap.  You may need both.

**[Static LAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation)** also known as link aggregation or bonding allows you to combine the throughput of multiple ports connected between the two or more devices.

**[VLAN trunking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLAN_Trunking_Protocol)** allows traffic from multiple vlans to cross a single link.

Comment: I like this differentiation: LAG is merging many physical links in to one logical link.  802.1Q Tagging is merging many logical links in to one physical link.

Aside: Unfortunately some platforms (Foundry) call LAG  "trunking".  So I always try to call it 802.1Q tagging instead of VLAN trunking.